# Return to the modal in case of error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im having modal window in front of index page ,when the model is valid I Redirect to the index view but when the model is not valid I want it to stay on the modal ,how should I do that ?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(
    [Bind(Include = "Id,name,user,test")] Roles goles)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.GCollection.Add(groupRoles);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //return View(groupRoles);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do some javascript.

1/ Return json from your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(
    [Bind(Include = "Id,name,user,test")] Roles goles)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.GCollection.Add(groupRoles);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new {Success=true, Redirect=@Url.Action("Index")});
    }

    var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorMessage) ? e.Exception.Message : e.ErrorMessage)).ToArray();

    return Json(new {Success=false, Errors = errors});
}
```

2/Submit your form using ajax. You should use [jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

```
$("#yourForm").ajaxForm({
    success:function(data){
        if(data.Success===true){
             // in case of success we redirect
             document.location.href= data.Redirect;
        }
        else{
             // Action in case of errors
             alert(data.Errors.join(", "));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but where is the place which is call to my modal,in the modal I have the errors since I add to them validations

Comment: @HolgerTans Sorry I do not understand your comment.

Comment: currently I have a modal pop up with some validation which I do in the controller,if the modal is OK I return the data to the index page if not I want that the modal will not closed and display the errors,how can I do that ?

Comment: @HolgerTans I have added a line in the action to retrieve automatically the errors from ModelState

Comment: and how should I call to the modal?

Comment: @HolgerTans How do you load your modal ? If you stick with my code you need to have a form with id "yourForm" in your modal.

Comment: I try to call to partial view and now it call to the modal but in new page and not on top the index and I lost all the styling of it,how should I call it in on top of the index page?